# Trying to login to Laravel API: 'The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.'

Tags: php, laravel, api

For college, I have this base Laravel project I was given, I need to follow along a video and work with it. At the beginning of the video, the teacher accesses laravel api with a get request with the program Insomnia, but when I do it I get the error:

'Route [login] not defined.'

After trying and failing to solve this, I tried to access the api/login page, and got this error:

'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.'

I added 'accept - application/json' to Insomnia header, which then gives me:

{
"error": "Unauthenticated."
}

My routes/api.php file

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//Route::post('login', 'LoginController@do')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'API\PassportController@login');
Route::post('register', 'API\PassportController@register');


Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {

    Route::get('user', 'API\PassportController@user');
    Route::get('logout', 'API\PassportController@logout');

    Route::resource('courses', 'API\CourseController')->except([
        'create', 'edit'
    ]);
    Route::resource('lecturers', 'API\LecturerController')->except([
        'create', 'edit'
    ]);
    Route::resource('enrolments', 'API\EnrolmentController')->except([
        'create', 'edit'
    ]);
});
```

Is there any other files that would be useful to put here?

The database has been migrated and seeded, I have tried clearing and refreshing the cache as well as creating new keys in git bash, I have added the only user and password from the database in insomnia. I can't find any solution that has worked so far and can't find any more people with this problem.

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: because you have `auth:api` and you did not provide token so you got the error `Unauthenticated`

Comment: I'm using v6.18.35, will providing a token maybe solve my problem, and if so, where do I put it?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `login` route is defined as a `POST` route that you can access using `POST` verb only, so when you call `api/login` you need to use `POST` instead of `GET`

Comment: Using POST on api/login gives me { "error": "Unauthenticated." }

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to provide the token.

For `get` you can just put it in the `Query String` like this:

```php
'/api/user?api_token=' + token
```

For `post` you can either put it in `Request Payload` or as `Bearer Token`

`Request Payload` send with the request.

```js
'api_token' => token,
```

`Bearer Token` send with the headers

```js
'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' + token,
```

And of course, all of these assume you have the correct Database setup.

Read the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication#database-preparation) to set up your Database

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand very well. How do I find what the token is to put it in the query string or any of the others?